# How can I interpret the following paragraph regarding single moms?

Tags: interpretación

I have to answer questions about [an article](http://world-language-h.hs.tenafly.k12.nj.us/modules/locker/files/get_group_file.phtml?gid=2298417&fid=22295334). The last question to which I have to tell if it is True/False is:

> 5. En general, la causa por la cual algunas madres son solteras es siempre muy similar.

The paragraph that I found that may help is:

> Generalmente se cree que madre soltera es una mujer que tuvo un hijo fuera del matrimonio y no necesariamente esto es así. Ser madre soltera puede ser resultado de un divorcio, del fallecimiento del cónyuge o en el peor de los casos por una violación. En todos estos casos la mujer asume el compromiso de criar sola a sus hijos.

I believe the question is true because in all of the situations the goal of the mother is to raise her kids. What do you think?

Comment: It's not asking about the goal, rather the cause.

Comment: So it's false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks to validate the reasons why single mothers exist, or in other words: Why (similarity of circumstances) does a woman become a single mom? Is it often for the same reasons?

So I would say the answer to the question is false.

The paragraph states that even though the general belief (**) is that single moms exist because they procreate outside a marriage, the writer later explains that single moms exist because of a number of different reasons: a divorce, a decease of the spouse, or even worst, rape.

(**) I would presume that this is the Latin American way of thinking...

Comment: Okay. Also, why does the question say "la causa" (singular)?

Comment: Because each mother has just one 'causa' acording to the study.

Comment: @Hello, it says "la causa" (singular) because it is referring to the particular cause for each mother, which the question points to be very similar to the cause for other mothers.

Comment: @Hello using singular in that case doesn't seem right. You can either say: *la causa por la cual algunas madres son solteras es siempre la misma* or *las causas por las cuales algunas madres son solteras son siempre muy similares*. But as it is written it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer like "false". The paragraph you gave lists some reasons why a woman could be a single mother.

I think the question wants to check if you realized that there is not a single cause (noticed the "se cree que madre soltera es una mujer que tuvo un hijo fuera del matrimonio y no necesariamente esto es así"), and understood the many and varied reasons listed right after.

That all those women chose to carry on being a single parent (or had no option) has nothing to do with what caused them to be single mothers.

So its false, because even if all of them carried on for the same reason (raising their kids best they could) the reason why they have to do it by themselves are many, according to the article.